# Is it possible to enter a text in a textbox without specific Element ID

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Im doing a test that enter text in the textbox but it dont have specific ID so everytime i run the test it will change. im using selenium webdriver in java please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can work. You can google for them and see how they work.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("cssSelector"));
driver.findElement(By.name("name"));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("linkText"));
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("partialLinkText"));
driver.findElement(By.className("className"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
```

I am sure some of them will be useful. Please let me know if you want more info.
The easiness of using them is in the order which i have mentioned.

Comment: CssSelector is by far the best means of finding things on the screen (apart from id) if you know how to use css. It should be much higher up that list.

Answer (score 1):

What means doesn't have a specific ID?If id at least partially remains the same you can use the CSS locator

```
driver.findElement(By.cssLocator("input[id*=somePartWhichNotChange]"));
//* star means contains
```

if not, then you can use `cssSelector` to get to your element like `"body table input"` or use `xpath` as a last resort.